# Nginx inside ASP.NET Core Docker container

Tags: azure, docker, nginx, asp.net-core

Unfortunately there is not much documentation about how is it possible to inject Nginx or Apache proxy into ASP.NET Core Docker container.
Here is nice manual that works, but it has separate images for ASP.NET Core application and Nginx.

[ASP.NET Core API behind the Nginx Reverse Proxy with Docker.](https://medium.com/@nicolastakashi/asp-net-core-api-behind-the-nginx-reverse-proxy-with-docker-72eeccfb5063)

I want to host my Docker image on Azure, so I need to have Nginx inside my Docker container.

Based on this article [Nginx Reverse Proxy to ASP.NET Core – Same Docker Container](https://www.sep.com/sep-blog/2017/02/24/nginx-reverse-proxy-to-asp-net-core-same-container/) I have created this configuration:

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
sendfile on;

proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

upstream app_servers {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://app_servers;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils

RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y nginx

WORKDIR /src

COPY MyApp.csproj MyApp.csproj
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

RUN rm -f /app/startup.sh
COPY startup.sh /app
RUN chmod 755 /app/startup.sh

RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000
EXPOSE 5000 80

CMD ["sh", "/app/startup.sh"]
```

**Startup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
service nginx start
dotnet /app/MyApp.dll
```

Still receive "Service unavailable"
May be because I have Azure AAD authentication.
Can someone recommend something or provide another working configuration?

Comment: _Here is nice manual that works, but it has separate images for ASP.NET Core application and Nginx_ That exactly **IS THE ANSWER** and correct way to do it. One application per docker container. You use something like [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) or equivalent of other ochestration tools to start/deploy multiple containers at the same time which have dependencies on each other. And you can also host multiple containers on azure, dunno where the problem is. Though the natural choice for azure hosting is to use azure app service for single application

Comment: Everything else makes no sense. Docker is not a virtual machine where you run an OS inside it and  will make all advantages of having docker in the first place obsolete. The big advantage of docker is that you can deploy applications independently (nginx from asp.net core app) and update the one w/o recreating the whole image. What you want sounds more like creating an VM and run **multiple** services inside it. For that you **don't need**. Don't use docker because **it's cool and everyone uses it** or have another buzzword in your cv. Use docker for what **it was made for**

Comment: Can't mark it as an answer, but seems it is. Thank you, @Tseng. Seems solution is to use this article (in future, when it would be not in preview) [Docker Compose deployment support in Azure Service Fabric (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-docker-compose) or Swarm or something else..

Comment: Awesome.  For all the all the purists on 1app per container - true, but sometimes there is a need for this manner.  This answer is great because it helped me achieve this method and I'm sure it help many others past and down the road.

Comment: Alex. Did you get it working. Few thoughts , have you tried to get into the container in the interactive mode and run curl localhost:5000 to see if your app work inside the container. Also I have tried copy the proxy related thing to /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

Comment: Hi @Matt. Exactly in current case I have decided to install ingress with tiller for my Kubernetes cluster. And I am using ingress instead of proxy. Since 2018 there have been a lot of changes in Azure. Now it is much more simple to use containers in Azure.

Comment: Hi @Alex, Good to know that it's working. For the benefit of SO users, it would be helpful if you post your approach/solution

Answer (score 0):

Tseng Jun was right in comments. Hosting nginx together with application in same container is not possible or not recommended.

I have ended up with creating [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) from Nginx image.
Has installed it with [Helm](https://helm.sh/).
As my Kubernetes cluster was in Azure I have used next one manual:
[Create an HTTPS ingress controller on Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls)

Answer (score 0):

I have some Azure Linux WebApps using docker-compose to serve Asp.Net Core 3.1 Apps with Nginx as a reverse proxy (they also have WebJobs running there). The WebApps have public repositories at GitHub, Docker registry and Azure Pipelines.

https://pdf.ricardogaefke.com/

https://webjobs.ricardogaefke.com/

You can check for public repos at `How it works` pages.